# I get no data when i retrieve values from Context

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was working on a shopping website this morning, using React Typescript and Context API ...
for the products, I used an open API from the web to retrieve some data (for the test), and I used that data as an initial state for my `[products, setProducts]` ...
when I `console.log(products)` my products state inside the Context File, I do get the data but when I `console.log` it in the App after using the provider I get an ***empty Array***...
I have no idea why that's happening...
thanks for your help

***Context API File***

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from "react-query";





type IProductContext = [IProductItem[] | undefined, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<IProductItem[] | undefined>>];

export const ProductContext = React.createContext<IProductContext>([[], () => null]);

const getProducts = async (): Promise<IProductItem[]> => 
await (await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")).json();


const ProductProvider: React.FC<{}> = ({children}: { children?: React.ReactNode }) => {

    //Retrieve the data and status using UseQuery
    const {data, isLoading, error} = useQuery<IProductItem[]>('products', getProducts);

    const [products, setProducts] = React.useState<IProductItem[] | undefined>(data || undefined);
    

    console.log(products)

    return (
        <ProductContext.Provider value={[products, setProducts]}>
            {children}
        </ProductContext.Provider>
    );

};

export default ProductProvider;


export function useProducts(){
    const context = React.useContext(ProductContext);

    if(!context) throw new Error('useProducts must be inside a ProductProvider.');

    return context;
}
```

***Types File***

```
interface IProductItem{
    id: number
    title: string
    description: string;
    category: string;
    image: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
}

type ProductType = {
    items: IProductItem[]
    saveItem: (item: ICartItem) => void
    updateItem: (id: number) => void
    removeItem: (id: number) => void
};
```

***My App.tsx file***

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import ProductProvider, {useProducts} from './infoContext/ProductContext';


function App() {

  const [products, setProducts] = useProducts()

  return (
    <ProductProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          test
          {
            console.log(products) 
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </ProductProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.useState` will use the passed value only the first time the component is rendered. To alter the value stored in the state you need to use the `useProducts` function.

In your case you should use a `useEffect` in the provider that updates the `products` when the `data` is changed.

Something like

```
const ProductProvider: React.FC<{}> = ({children}: { children?: React.ReactNode }) => {

    //Retrieve the data and status using UseQuery
    const {data, isLoading, error} = useQuery<IProductItem[]>('products', getProducts);

    const [products, setProducts] = React.useState<IProductItem[] | undefined>(data || undefined);
    

    console.log(products)

    React.useEffect( ()=> {
        setProducts(data);
    }, [data]);

    return (
        <ProductContext.Provider value={[products, setProducts]}>
            {children}
        </ProductContext.Provider>
    );

};
```

Comment: thank you that works...  Tho the data keeps on charging... How do i do to make sure it updates once in a long time to prevent reloading the components